# remove a part of url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website on my localhost and an url is http://localhost:8484/myweb/onboard

how can I change the url to be like 
http://localhost:8484/myweb/ without onboard but still point to the same page, is it possibele ?

Answer (score 1):

Just try with following htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^$ onboard/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ onboard/$1
```

don't forgot to enable rewrite_module in server

Comment: no it's not working, 
i still have onboard on my link

Comment: Clear history in browser and try

Comment: I did but still the same